# Fetching information from Roblox API about a game

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, discord.js

I am trying to fetch information from: https://games.roblox.com/v1/games?universeIds=3759152694

But having it try to response with "response.data[0]" (I use jsonpathfinder) it gives me undefined. When I try to do "response.data[0].id" it says that id is not defined. I have not messed with apis in quite a while so I may be just missing something here. Any help is appreciated!

```js
const axios = require("axios");

module.exports = {
    name: "info",
    execute: async (bot, message, args) => {
        test = {
            data: [
                {
                    id: 3759152694,
                    rootPlaceId: 10269801695,
                    name: "unnamed sim",
                    description: "soon",
                    sourceName: "unnamed sim",
                    sourceDescription: "soon",
                    creator: { id: 3593901883, name: "Jack1286401", type: "User", isRNVAccount: false, hasVerifiedBadge: false },
                    price: null,
                    allowedGearGenres: ["All"],
                    allowedGearCategories: [],
                    isGenreEnforced: false,
                    copyingAllowed: false,
                    playing: 0,
                    visits: 0,
                    maxPlayers: 6,
                    created: "2022-07-18T14:21:46.03Z",
                    updated: "2022-07-22T08:17:08.8213451Z",
                    studioAccessToApisAllowed: false,
                    createVipServersAllowed: false,
                    universeAvatarType: "MorphToR15",
                    genre: "All",
                    isAllGenre: true,
                    isFavoritedByUser: false,
                    favoritedCount: 0,
                },
            ],
        };
        await axios.get("https://games.roblox.com/v1/games?universeIds=3759152694").then(function (response) {
            // handle success
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data[0]));
        });
    },
};
```

JSON Table:

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 3759152694,
            "rootPlaceId": 10269801695,
            "name": "unnamed sim",
            "description": "soon",
            "sourceName": "unnamed sim",
            "sourceDescription": "soon",
            "creator": { "id": 3593901883, "name": "Jack1286401", "type": "User", "isRNVAccount": false, "hasVerifiedBadge": false },
            "price": null,
            "allowedGearGenres": ["All"],
            "allowedGearCategories": [],
            "isGenreEnforced": false,
            "copyingAllowed": false,
            "playing": 0,
            "visits": 0,
            "maxPlayers": 6,
            "created": "2022-07-18T14:21:46.03Z",
            "updated": "2022-07-22T08:17:08.8213451Z",
            "studioAccessToApisAllowed": false,
            "createVipServersAllowed": false,
            "universeAvatarType": "MorphToR15",
            "genre": "All",
            "isAllGenre": true,
            "isFavoritedByUser": false,
            "favoritedCount": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You could try logging the actual response to see its structure.

Comment: I got some help earlier on discord, apparently I had to do "response.data.data[0].id"